# AWS ElasticSearch on private subnet - safe to have no signed url/access policy?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have an ES cluster setup within our VPC and attached to one of our private subnets. It's also attached to a security group allowing access from particular instances. I have the following policy attached:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "our::arn:*"
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is, from what I can tell, this should mean that publicly, this cluster should not be accessible right? I've done some testing and that seems correct but just want to make sure I am not missing anything